# Combobox selected value onto excel

Tags: excel, vb.net, visual-studio

I'm working on a class project that requires me to ask for user input and it requires it to export it onto an excel worksheet. I've been searching for a way to user the `ComboBox.SelectedItem` property into it but I couldn't figure it out. The following keeps giving me a NULL error and I can't figure out why. The ComboBox is created in Visual Studio.

```
        objSheet.Cells(Y, 1).Value = txtTel.Text
        objSheet.Cells(Y, 2).Value = txtEmail.Text
        objSheet.Cells(Y, 3).Value = txtSurname.Text
        objSheet.Cells(Y, 4).Value = txtName.Text
        objSheet.Cells(Y, 5).Value = ComboBox1.SelectedItem
```

Comment: Is it a single-selection combobox, or a multi-selection one?  No, forget that, I'm thinking of list boxes.

Comment: Is the combobox on an Excel UserForm?  Or is it on a form you created in Visual Studio?  Or is it a combobox on an Excel sheet?  (It would certainly help narrow the problem if we knew whether you were using VBA or VB.Net!)

Comment: I should of probably mentions that its a combobox created in Visual Studio. I'm also using VB.Net

Comment: I would recommend that you get rid of the [vba] tag then - you could even create an MCVE of just the one line `Dim s As String = ComboBox.SelectedItem` as the fact that you are trying to put the value obtained from a combobox into an Excel cell is nothing to do with your problem.  Your problem is simply how to access the combobox value.

Comment: Is the name of your combobox object actually `ComboBox`, or is it something like `ComboBox1`?  (You seem to have given meaningful names to your other controls, so I would have expected you to give a meaningful name to the combobox.)

Comment: The name was ComboBox1 my fault. Also yes I have the code under the submit button sub so as soon as the button is clicked it fills out the excel speadsheet and I can't figure out how to access the value of the combobox as using 'combobox1.selecteditem' gives me a null error

Comment: Has an item been selected?  If not, you would **expect** to receive a Null.  (["Property Value - Type: System.Object - The object that is the currently selected item or null if there is no currently selected item."](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selecteditem(v=vs.110).aspx))

Comment: I also suggest you edit the question to include the **exact** error message you are getting.

Comment: If you want the text described on the ComboBox, try using `ComboBox1.SelectedText` instead. Also, verify if the `SelectedIndex` property isn't `-1`.

Answer (score 1):

ComboBox1.SelectedItem if it is not working
Use anyone of below:
ComboBox1.Text
ComboBox1.SelectedText

I hope first one may solve your error